# favicon.ico redirect rule possible (no html)?

Tags: browser, webserver

i was wondering if its possible to set some kind of rule maybe in .htaccess ? so that if a browser tries to load the default /favicon.ico that it can instead serve my /images/favicon-mushroom-48.png file instead and would the browser accept it ?

the reason i want this is that i have a link to it in my index so it displays correctly BUT if someone clicks on an image in my gallery then its just an image display without html so the browser tries to load the default /favicon.ico and is why i was thinking of some kind of redirect rule

i know its an oddball request but ive seen some amazingly technical solutions on this forum for so many things so if any place knows how to do it then this is it im sure

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution, just save `/images/favicon-mushroom-48.png` as `/favicon.ico`

It's probably abusing something but the browser seems to load it fine

I'll leave this open if someone wants post the right way to do it :D

Thanks